# Unable to Block Kubernetes Ports in iptables

Tags: iptables, kubernetes

I'm currently working on securing my Kubernetes server by blocking certain ports using iptables. I've applied the following rules to drop traffic on specific ports:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30880 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30088 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30080 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30000:32000 -j DROP
```

However, despite adding these rules, I'm still able to see the supposedly blocked ports when I run an Nmap scan from another server:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.201.79
Host is up (0.0026s latency).
Not shown: 65528 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp    open   ssh
80/tcp    open   http
443/tcp   open   https
30080/tcp open   unknown
30088/tcp open   unknown
30500/tcp open   unknown
30880/tcp closed unknown
```

Here is the output of `iptables -S`:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-N KUBE-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-N KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY
-N KUBE-NODEPORTS
-N KUBE-PROXY-CANARY
-N KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30880 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30088 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30080 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30000:32000 -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes load balancer firewall" -j KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes health check service ports" -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes load balancer firewall" -j KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes load balancer firewall" -j KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES -p tcp -m comment --comment "kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-svc has no endpoints" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -m tcp --dport 30443 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-FIREWALL ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m comment --comment "block incoming localnet connections" -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j DROP
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints" -m udp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.104.22.122/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.100.159.144/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-svc has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 9090 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 53 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:metrics has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 9153 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.103.232.189/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/metrics-server:https has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I'm unsure why the ports are not being blocked as expected. Could someone help me understand what might be causing this behavior? Are there any modifications I should make to my iptables rules or server configuration to effectively block these ports?